# Unity WWW: Post a request to an URL with custom headers

Tags: c#

I am using  C# to try retrieve a token and my code is based on this example:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html

```
IEnumerator Start() {
  string urlToken = "myUrl";

  WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
  form.AddField ("username", username);
  form.AddField ("password", password);

  Hashtable header = form.headers;//where I am getting my error*

  header.Add("content-type", "application/json"); //header I need send over


  WWW tokenRequest = new WWW (urlToken, form, header); 

  yield return tokenRequest;
  print ("Anything back?" + tokenRequest.bytesDownloaded);
}
```

***Assets/WWWDemo.cs(46,19): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary to System.Collections.Hashtable**

How would the header be assigned correctly? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form.header is a `Dictionary<string, string>` - you need to do this

```
form.headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
```

or this (my preference)

```
var headers = form.headers;
headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
```

or this

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
```

Then your WWW constructor needs to be called like this

```
WWW tokenRequest = new WWW(urlToken, form.data, header);
```

because the 2nd parameter is a byte[] and not a Form (you missed that part out from the tutorial).

Comment: The first option removes the error in the question. Now the www object gives me error CS1502 when I pass it 3 arguments (__new WWW (urlToken, form_1, form_1.headers)__). Tried passing only two arguments, but my url won't accept either (I guess it doesn't see the needed header).

Comment: I see the problem. I've updated my answer to include that too.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested it, but maybe you can try:

```
header["content-type"] = "application/json";
```

Anyway, as a note, if this is a real example; the `content-type` header is typically sent by the server, is not a request header

Comment: That's not accurate. When posting form data it is used to inform the server how the content was encoded.